# c# what takes processing time?

Tags: c#, time, processing

I'm doing a program for video processing in which the time is very critical. I'm not having any difficulties in the program, but I would like to know from you, what things in coding takes most processing time? loops? if statements? goto statements ? functions? writing/reading text files ? other things? my program contains alot of each on of the above, and i would like to know which things take the most time so that I can try to minimize the time ( even 1 second matter in my application )

Comment: This is not the right way to figure out where performance issues will arise.  Use a profiler instead.

Comment: All of those take time.  Get a good performance profiler, see what the slowest spots are, then tackle those.

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to give a precise answer using the data above. It most likely will be in some library calls to the video processing library, but this is just guesswork.

The only sensible answer is therefore: Use a profiler to find out where exactly your program spents it's time.

A [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) is a program that analyzes your program and determines where it spends its time.

Comment: The redgate profiler is easy to use and has a 30 day trial. Link: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Comment: would you tell me what a profiler is ? if you would provide me with some usefull links, it is really my first time to hear about that

Comment: Another good indicator of potential performance bottleneck are subroutines with high growth rates. Look into [Big O Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o).

Answer (score 0):

I agree about using the profiler. In some cases using the profiler might slow the program too much or take too much memory. in such cases an informed use of time measurment using:  [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

might do the trick.